# Why is my date comparison not working?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a requirement that if a user has forgotten their password, they should request and receive a **forgotten password** link via email to reset their password.

I am using a date time comparison along with a  token in form of a unique code to ensure a certain level of security.

As soon as they receive an email link to reset the password and the user clicks on the link to reset password, the user is presented with a screen to reset password. This is working great so far.

What I am having problems with is when a user clicks on the email link to reset their password more than 24 hours after the email with link was sent, they get a blank page.

We want the user to get a page that says, **Reset password link has expired. It was for one time use only** but that message is not visible.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code I am using:

```
If dr.HasRows Then
    Dim dtCreate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim dtNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim dtExp As DateTime = dtCreate.AddDays(1)
    If dtNow > dtExp Then
        ResetPwdPanel.Visible = False
        Expired.Visible = True
    Else
        ResetPwdPanel.Visible = True
        Expired.Visible = False
        lblExpired.Text = "Reset password link has expired. It was for one time use only"
        Return

    End If
End If
```

'Markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>

<asp:Panel ID="ResetPwdPanel" runat="server" Visible="false" >

<fieldset style="width:400px">

<legend>Reset Password</legend>    

<table>

<tr>

<td>New password: </td><td>
    <div class="input text"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewPwd" style="width:150px;" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div><br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNewPwd" runat="server" 

        ControlToValidate="txtNewPwd" Display="Dynamic" 

        ErrorMessage="Please enter new password" ForeColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>Confirm Passsword: </td><td>
<div class="input text"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtConfirmPwd" style="width:150px;" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div><br />

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvConfirmPwd" runat="server" 

        ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPwd" Display="Dynamic" 

        ErrorMessage="Please re-enter password to confirm" ForeColor="Red" 

        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmvConfirmPwd" runat="server" 

        ControlToCompare="txtNewPwd" ControlToValidate="txtConfirmPwd" 

        Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Password didn't match" ForeColor="Red" 

        SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:CompareValidator>

    </td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td>

    &nbsp;</td><td>

    <asp:Button ID="btnChangePwd" runat="server" Text="Change Password" 

            onclick="btnChangePwd_Click" /></td>

</tr>

    <tr>

        <td colspan="2">

            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>

</fieldset>        

</asp:Panel>

 <asp:panel ID="Expired" runat="server">
   <asp:Label ID="lblExpired" runat="server" Text="" style="color: #FF0000"></asp:Label></asp:panel>
```

We have two panel controls. One that shows reset password controls (this works) whilst the other shows the reset password link expiration message (this does not work).

Comment: A blank screen is not very helpful. There is always more information somewhere. In IIS logging, F12 tools, interactive debugging. Take the first step to solving your problem and look past the 'blank screen' result

Comment: @Tairoc: It may help if you added a snippet of the .aspx showing the markup for your panels, plus their parent controls if there are any. Also, by "blank page" do you mean a white screen without *any* content whatsoever, or do you just mean that the expiration message isn't visible?

Comment: `dtNow > dtExp` can never be true based on your code

Comment: I agree with Alex. I think that is part of the problem. You need to store the date and time of when the link was sent. Add 24 hours to that and then compare that with `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I really appreciate it. I have updated the code above to include the markup as requested. I also realized I mistakenly left out the message that should show a user that his/her link to reset password has expired.

Also, to answer the question of what blank screen means, it means that when the link to password reset is more than 24 hours, then it can no longer be used and user is shown a message that the link has expired. That message is not visible if dtNow is greater than dtExp and we would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

if still more than 24 hours is the scenario then do the `Equal or =`

like this

```
If DateOfCreation = DateTime.Now then

    msgbox "Reset"
else
        msgbox "Expired"
End if
```

based on your code

```
If dr.HasRows Then
                Dim dtCreate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
                Dim dtNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now

                If dtCreate = dtNow Then


 ResetPwdPanel.Visible = True
                    Expired.Visible = False
                    Return
                Else
                      ResetPwdPanel.Visible = False
                    Expired.Visible = True

                End If
            End If
```

Comment: Sorry ro disagree with you but using the <> expression is not going to work.

dtNow is either greater (>) than dtExpt or dtNow is less than (<) .

Comment: try to use `grether than` only `<`

Comment: What is dateofCreation? Did you mean the date user was added to database table?

If yes, how is that supposed to work in this case when our business rule is to give user 24 hours to reset his or her password?

If password not reset within 24 hours, link becomes unusable.